# Открытие и чтение файла, запись в файл, помещение результата в файл

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, текст, запись

есть алгоритм решения задачи. Не знаю только каким способом открыть файлы и как в них что-либо записывать (для файлов f1 и f2) и помещать результат (для файла g). Обычными методами не получается. Либо я что-то делаю не так.
Вот сама задача:

Даны два символьных файла f1 и f2. В f1 - произвольный текст, слова в котором разделены пробелами и знаками препинания. В f2 - не более 40 слов, которые разделены запятыми. Эти слова образуют пару: первое слово считается заменяемым, а второе – заменяющим. Нужно найти в f1 все заменяемые слова и заменить их на заменяющие. Результат поместить в файл g.

Если для открытия, чтения, записи и всего подобного требуется изменить алгоритм решения, то смело меняйте, это не принципиально.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

string parse(fstream* f1,fstream* f2)
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    typedef map<string, string> DictArr; //Для удобства 
    //Получение слов из файла F2
    DictArr slovar;
    while (!f2->eof())
    {
        string src_word;
        string sub_word;
        getline(*f2, src_word, ',');//Получаем заменяемое слово
        getline(*f2, sub_word, ',');//Получаем заменитель
        slovar[src_word] = sub_word;//Вносим заменяемое слово(ключ) и заменитель(значение) в ассоциативный массив(словарь)
    }
    //Разбор строки
    string dannyefposleobr;//Содержание файла после обработки
    string tekslovo;//Текущее слово
    //Считываем файл с текстом
    cout << "Parsing data from file F1 ";
    while (!f1->eof())
    {
        char raz;//Разделитель
        f1->get(raz);//Считываем символ
        //Проверяем "А знак ли это препинания?"
        if (raz == ' ' || raz == ',' || raz == '.' || raz == ':' || raz == '!' || raz == '?' || raz == '!' || raz == ';' || raz == '-')
        {
            DictArr::iterator iter = slovar.find(tekslovo);/*Если мы получили знак препинания, 
            то слово считано и можно начать его поиск в словаре*/
            if (iter == slovar.end())//Если слово не нашли, то копируем как есть и прибавляем разделитель
            {
                dannyefposleobr += tekslovo + raz;
            }
            else
            {
                dannyefposleobr += slovar[tekslovo] + raz;/*Если нашли, 
                тогда заменим слово ее значением из словаря и прибавим разделитель*/
            }
            tekslovo.clear();//Слово внесено в dannyefposleobr, следовательно на данный момент слов в буффере нет - чистим переменную
        }
        //Если считанный символ не разделитель, значит это часть слова - помещаем символ в tekslovo
        else
        {
            tekslovo += raz;
        }
    }
    cout << "Done\n";
    return dannyefposleobr;
}
```

Comment: "Не знаю только каким способом открыть файлы и как в них что-либо
 записывать".  Это  нехорошая новость... Каков вопрос?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вместо 'int main()' должно было стоять 'string parse(fstream* f1,fstream* f2)'

Comment: И вот как раз на это и ругается программа, если я пытаюсь стандартно открывать и записывать файлы

Comment: Пишет что выражение должно иметь тип класса. А классы которые я использую в этой программе не содержат члена open и др.

Comment: @llatibro,  `while (!f2->eof())` -- не стоит так программировать, поскольку конец файла (`EOF`)  распознается **после какого-либо чтения**, а не перед ним